# Adding ToolBar to my Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a Button on a `UIViewController`. When i click on this Button, a `UIToolBar` gets displayed (Above the TabBarController). Now when i scroll the view down and click the Button the UIToolBar gets displayed at a different location (way above the tababar). What i want is to display the `UIToolBar` right above the TabBar at all instances (even when i scroll the page up or down and click the Button).

My code so far :

```
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300 , 320 , 55)];
```

According to this Code, i have given the `X` and `Y` cordinates of the toolBar to be `0` and `323`. So even when i scroll the view up or down and click on the button, the toolbar will display at this location.

So how can i modify my code, to display it right above the TabBar at all instances. (Even when i scroll the view up or down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is: You are adding the toolbar on the view with the coordinate hardcoded to (0, 300 , 320 , 55). And this is with respect to the view. But not the iphone screen or window. after adding when you scroll the view, you can see that the view contents are also scrolled up.

All you have to do is:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300 , 320 , 55)];
[mainWindow addSubview:toolBar];
[mainwindow bringSubviewToFront:toolBar];
```

Comment: Ok, but need i add mainWindow to self.View. like this  [self.view addSubView:mainWindow];  ??

Comment: you can access main window from anywhere in your project. just try out the code. you cannot add the mainwindow on any view. Window is the base for all other views.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends where you will add your toolBar as a subview. If you want it always to be in the same place add it to the current `UIWindow` object.

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300 , 320 , 55)];
```

on button click add the toolBar as a subview to the main window

```
[mainWindow addSubview:toolBar];
```

Comment: 1.) So when i scroll up or down, the UIToolBar Will always display right above the UITabBar ? 2.) Shouldn't i add mainWindow to self.view as [self.view addSubView:mainWindow]; ??

Comment: 1. Yes it will stay regardless of your scroll action. 2. No you should not. mainWindow is already displayed all you have to do is add your UIToolBar to it.

Comment: Strange, my comment about why this was a poor answer has been removed. How did that happen?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need to implement the following hierarchy:

```
UITabBarController
   V
UINavigationController
   V
Your view controller
```

A `UINavigationController` has a `toolbar` property that can be displayed or hidden using its `setToolbarHidden:animated:` method.

The toolbar appears directly above the tab bar, as per your question.

If you add a toolbar as a subview of your scroll view, you need handle the scroll view delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:` and reposition the scroll view each time it's fired.

That method - and adding a scroll view to the main window - both have the downside of covering part of the scroll view. Using a nav controller's toolbar, the height of your view controller's view is automatically reduced by the height of the toolbar so there is no overlap.

See the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW30) for a full description.

Comment: So will i be able to change the position of the UIToolBar too ? if so How?

Comment: Reading your question, I thought you wanted the tool bar to be appear directly above the tab bar. That is the behaviour for a UINavigationController tab bar.

Comment: Whoever voted this answer down, please leave a comment so I can improve it. Thanks.